# I lost my Irish passport. Can I travel to Thailand and back from the UK using my US passport?

Tags: uk, dual-nationality, lost-documents, customs-and-immigration

My EU passport was stolen and I am going on holiday to Thailand from the UK this week. I have dual nationality and a US passport, can I use this to leave and re enter the UK?

Comment: Do you live permanently in the UK? How long are you going to Thailand for? How long until you travel?

Comment: Hi Richard, I do live and work permanently in the UK, I’ll be in Thailand for 2 weeks and I’m travelling on Wednesday. Will I be able to leave the country with no issues? Is getting back in going to be the problem? I’ve tried calling many places: Heathrow, immigration, US embassy, Irish embassy and I can get through to anyone or I’m told I’m talking to the wrong person!

Comment: I would suggest to reach out to the Irish consulate to receive emergency passport or similar. You could visit Thailand with a US passport, but coming back you should identify as EU citizen to avoid issues.

Comment: @johannes as outlined in my answer, the UK's immigration regulations (and the EU directive on which they are based) explicitly provide that an EU citizen can prove that citizenship by means other than a passport or ID card.

Comment: @phoog, yes, and a consulate is a good place to ask what options exist while not being in the home country, especially as they typically have all materials to also produce temporary passports, which aren't good to ravel away, (no chip, no 6 month validity etc.) but good enough to go back

Comment: @johannes oh I see, you were suggesting the Irish consulate in the Philippines?  I had assumed you meant the Irish consulate in the UK.  Yes, getting an emergency passport while in the Philippines would simply the return to the UK.  It is definitely something Sm1200 should consider.

Answer (score 13):

You can certainly do this, but you may have trouble entering the UK at the end of your trip, because you will either have to lie about your intentions in the UK, which is a terrible idea, or convince them through other means that you are an Irish citizen and therefore entitled to enter and reside in the UK.

The specific law that allows you to enter as an Irish citizen without an Irish passport is regulation 11(4) of the [Immigration (European Economic Area) Regulations 2016](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2016/1052), which says

> (4) Before an immigration officer refuses admission to the United Kingdom to a person under this regulation because the person does not produce on arrival a document mentioned in paragraph (1) or (2), the immigration officer must provide every reasonable opportunity for the document to be obtained by, or brought to, the person or allow the person to prove by other means that the person is—
>
> (a) an EEA national;
>
> ...

It will help to have a credible explanation of why you do not have your Irish passport with you, so do bring the police report showing that your passport was stolen.  You should probably bring as much additional evidence of your Irish citizenship as you can possibly get your hands on before you leave.  The police report might be enough, but more evidence can only help.

Also see the related question [Immigration officer stamped “Indefinite leave to enter UK” in US passport of EU citizen. How to fix it?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/87236/19400), in which a Swedish/US dual national was admitted on the basis of Swedish nationality (albeit with an incorrect stamp) after presenting a US passport; in that case, the traveler didn't even mention the EU nationality until after the officer asked.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** 
If you have entered the EU  using US passport than you can also leave the EU using US passport and no one will ask you a question.

**Option 2:** 
But in your case you are living permanently in UK (and I think your residency is based on EU passport and you have entered the EU with your Irish passport), you have to file a police complaint about  the lost passport (and request the police report if possible). Then you can apply new passport using "Online Passport Renewal Service" or go to the nearest Irish Embassy or Consulate.  There you have  to wait a minimum of eight working days. But with valid proof of confirmed travel  (e.g. airline ticket/email) the application can be processed sooner with additional fee. Get the time slot as soon as possible

**Option 3:** [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel)

Comment: There is no need to leave the UK with the Irish passport.  Can you point to an authoritative source that says otherwise?

Comment: Embassy of Ireland, Great Britain - https://www.dfa.ie/irish-embassy/great-britain/passports/top-passport-questions/can-i-get-my-passport-today/

Comment: Which text on that page supports the claim that Sm1200 can only use the US passport to leave the UK if that was the passport used to enter the UK?

Comment: read the option 3 before you ask time wasting questions.

Comment: Ok, then let me rephrase my comment as a statement rather than a question: your option 1 is incorrect.  It should read "You can leave the UK using your US passport."  There is no need for the conditional "if" clause.

Comment: yes, he can leave the UK even on US passport but for that he has to explain everything at immigration.  No body can stop him to leave the country but he has to convince the immigration officer and that can last long. Got it or not?

Comment: The UK does not have exit immigration control.  If you want to discuss further, please [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93002/discussion-between-phoog-and-sharp).

Comment: Think logically.  Yes, he can leave but when he enters then?

Comment: Speaking of "entering the EU" in this context is _at best_ horribly misleading -- especially since none of the EU member states in question are part of the Schengen area. There are simply no rules that depend on matching up entries to and exits from **the EU** as such.

Comment: @Henning Makholm Source?

Comment: As support for @HenningMakholm's claim, see for example recital 42 of the [Schengen Borders Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1556561498624&uri=CELEX:32016R0399) and recital 52 of [Regulation 2017/2226](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1556561624846&uri=CELEX:32017R2226), establishing the Schengen Entry/Exit System (which is not yet operational).  As to the prospects on re-entry, see my answer and the question I linked to there.